# Assembly language : Why is my string printed at wrong places

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios, tasm, dosbox

I am using dosbox x86(windows) to run this program and I am running this program with .exe. Below here is part of the code.

```
.model  tiny
.data
    ui_c    db 0            ; counter for UI column
    _str0 db "Typing HERO!$"
    ...

.code
    main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    CALL    rand_init
    MOV     AH, 00h         ;Set size to 80x25
    MOV     AL, 03h
    INT     10h
    MOV     ch, 32          ;hide cursor
    MOV     ah, 1       
    INT     10h 

@UI:    
    MOV     BH,00h
    MOV     AH, 2
    MOV     DL,ui_c
    MOV     DH,19
    INT     10h
    MOV     AH, 9
    MOV     BL, 03h
    MOV     BH, 00
    MOV     CX, 1
    MOV     AL, 178
    INT     10h
    ADD     ui_c,1
    CMP     ui_c, 80
    je      menu
    JB      @UI


;/////////////////////////////////// Print Start Menu ///////////////////////////////////:

menu:   
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA     DX,_str0            ;print _str0 string
    INT 21H

    MOV     AH,13h
    MOV     BH,0h
    MOV     BL,06h
    MOV     AL,00h              ;Write mode
    MOV     CX,12               ;Number of char in Str.
    MOV     DL,35               ; Column
    MOV     DH,3                ; Row
    INT     10h
...
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

But this is what i get when I run the code:

[image]

I want my string "Typing Hero" to be at brown colour unknown symbol location instead of below the blue colour line. What should I changed so my string can stay at the location it should be.

Comment: With [Int 10h/ah=13h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0210.htm) you need to set ES:BP to point to the string you want to print. Because you haven't set ES:BP it is printing garbage. Remove the call to `MOV AH,09H
    LEA     DX,_str0            ;print _str0 string
    INT 21H`. Set ES at program entry by changing `mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax` to `mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax` `mov es, ax` and then before you call Int 10/ah=13h load BP with `LEA     BP,_str0`

Answer (score 1):

After the dos call to INT 21H, you havent set the ES:BP registers for the VGA call to INT 13H.

```
;The cheapest way to set ES to CS on an 8086 is a push/pop

    PUSH CS
    POP ES


;DX already contains the address of the string.

    MOV BP,DX


;The code youve written then follows...

MOV     AH,13h
MOV     BH,0h
MOV     BL,06h
MOV     AL,00h              ;Write mode
MOV     CX,12               ;Number of char in Str.
MOV     DL,35               ; Column
MOV     DH,3                ; Row
INT     10h
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanations aren't very helpful.  MichaelPetch's comment is a much better answer than this.  Also, why `push dx / pop bp` instead of `mov bp, dx` like a normal person?  You can't `mov` between two segment registers, but you can for GP-integer registers.

Comment: Its been a while since I did x86, wasnt sure if BP was MOVable. Posted something concise and self-explanatory that should work, but loading up a an OS with debug on it now to check that MOV BP, DX is not a macro.

Comment: BP is one of the 8 general-purpose registers that normal instructions can use, like `add bp, ax` or whatever.  That's also why it works in addressing modes.  You don't need to boot anything, just put that `mov` in a file by itself and assemble it with nasm / disassemble with `objdump -d` or `ndisasm` to see the encoding.  (Or take my word for it; the majority of my gold badges and rep on SO are/is from asm questions.)

Comment: Okay adjusted, BP is MOVable. I think the context of the question, the section Ive pulled and the way Ive highlighted my editions which are very simple to read, expresses something that makes what Ive posted as more than just a code dump. In "English --v" I could have written "You have neglected to provide the segment and address of the string that you wish to display" but I think that much can be gathered by someone who's already written enough to demonstate he can speak in 8086

Comment: Keep in mind that most of the future readers that could benefit from answers like this are are people who barely know what anything does.  Or for some other reason didn't already think of googling docs for the BIOS calls they're using and checking that against their own code.  Most competent people writing asm can debug this kind of bug on their own when a call doesn't do what they wanted.  It's somewhat clear that setting ES:BP is the new part in your code, even for future readers who might have code that's different from the question.  The fact that DX holds a pointer on input isn't stated.

Comment: Hows that Mr x86 Primary Maintainer? Im a noob to stack exchange so go easy.

Comment: That's *much* better.  In general if you want beginners to learn from an answer, explaining the "why" for each instruction or small group separately works well, as well as an overall "why".  Thanks for taking my feedback into consideration and putting in the time to make your answer better. :)